# Breaking early when computing cumulative products or sums in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have a range `r=numpy.array(range(1, 6))` and I am calculating the cumulative sum using `numpy.cumsum(r)`. But instead of returning `[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]` I would like it to return `[1, 3, 6]` because of the condition that the cumulative result must be less than 10.

If the array is very large, I would like the cumulative sum to break out before it starts calculating values that are redundant and will be thrown away later. Of course, I am trivializing everything here for the sake of the question.

Is it possible to break out of `cumsum` or `cumprod` early based on a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with any function in numpy, since in most cases these are meant for vectorized computations on fixed-length arrays. One obvious way to do what you want is to break out of a standard for-loop in Python (as I assume you know):

```
def limited_cumsum(x, limit):
    y = []
    sm = 0
    for item in x:
        sm += item
        if sm > limit:
            return y
        y.append(sm)
    return y
```

But this would obviously be an order of magnitude slower than numpy's cumsum.

Since you probably need some very specialized function, the changes are low to find the exact function you need in numpy. You should probably have a look at [Cython](http://cython.org/), which allows you to implement custom functions that are as flexible as a Python function (and using a syntax that is almost Python), with a speed close to that of C.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on size of the array you are computing the cumulative sum for and how quickly you expect the target value to be reached it may be quicker to calculate the cumulative sum in steps.

```
import numpy as np

size = 1000000
target = size
def stepped_cumsum():
    arr = np.arange(size)
    out = np.empty(len(arr), dtype=int) 
    step = 1000
    last_value = 0
    for i in range(0, len(arr), step):
        np.cumsum(arr[i:i+step], out=out[i:i+step])
        out[i:i+step] += last_value
        last_value = out[i+step-1]
        if last_value >= target:
            break
    else:
        return out
    greater_than_target_index = i + (out[i:i+step] >= target).argmax()
    # .copy() required so rest of backing array can be freed
    return out[:greater_than_target_index].copy()

def normal_cumsum():
    arr = np.arange(size)
    out = np.cumsum(arr)
    return out

stepped_result = stepped_cumsum()
normal_result = normal_cumsum()
assert (stepped_result < target).all()
assert (stepped_result == normal_result[:len(stepped_result)]).all()
```

Results:

```
In [60]: %timeit cumsum.stepped_cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit cumsum.normal_cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.69 ms per loop
```